# How to remove on/off text from switch in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

How to remove on/off text from switch

```
<Label Text="Below is the binded data: "></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding MyData}"></Label>
<Label x:Name="lbldisp"></Label>
<Switch Toggled="SwitchToggled"></Switch>
```

Answer (score 19):

> How to remove on/off text from switch

The native control corresponding to the `Switch` in UWP is `ToggleSwitch`. If you want to remove `on/off` content, you could create `ToggleSwitch` without text style directly in `UWP` project like following:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="OffContent" Value=" " />
        <Setter Property="OnContent" Value=" " />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-110,0" /> 
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Error: 'ToggleSwitch' not found

Comment: So if this didn't work just create custom control with custom native renderer and for uwp renderer set for control off/onContent to empty

Comment: This works, but in case you missed it you need to add it to the App.xaml in the UWP project, not the shared project. However, at least in my case, the 'content' section of the switch is now a massive white space compared to only the length of the On/Off string.. .haven't quite worked that one out yet.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me.  as @Lindsay noted, this goes in your UWP app.xaml, not the xamarin forms/shared project.

Comment: When I do this the Switch starts taking up all available width and the item that comes after it gets pushed to the right. What do I have to do to keep the width the same?

Comment: I added a negative margin to get rid of the extra padding.
`<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-110,0" />`

Answer (score 2):

I used an Effect to solve this one.

In your UWP project;

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("YOURAPP")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(YOURAPP.UWP.Effects.SwitchEffect), nameof(YOURAPP.UWP.Effects.SwitchEffect))]
namespace YOURAPP.UWP.Effects
{
    public class SwitchEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (Control is ToggleSwitch switchControl)
            {
                switchControl.OffContent = string.Empty;
                switchControl.OnContent = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        { }
    }
}
```

In your Forms project:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace YOURAPP.Effects
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class SwitchEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public SwitchEffect() : base("YOURAPP.SwitchEffect") { }
    }
}
```

In your XAML:
Add the namespace:

```
xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:YOURAPP.Effects;assembly=YOURAPP"

<Switch>
    <Switch.Effects>
        <effects:SwitchEffect />
    </Switch.Effects>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your UWP App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="OnContent" Value=""/>
        <Setter Property="OffContent" Value=""/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to do for specific switch rather changing toggle switches for whole UWP app

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="xyz" OnContent="" OffContent="">
</ToggleSwitch>
```